# Update customer address attribute value in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, database, customer-address

I have to remove leading and trailing spaces from address postcodes.

The following script does the task:

```
<?php
require('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::init();


$addresses = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();

foreach( $addresses as $row ) {
    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load( $row->getId()   );

    $address->setData( 'postcode', trim( $address->getPostcode() ) ) //remove spaces
            ->getResource()
            ->saveAttribute( $address, 'postcode' );
}
```

Is there any better solution? Can/should it be done directly via MySQL database query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Customer details are an EAV-based model, you are better off using the code you have entered.

However, if you really really want to edit MySQL directly, you can run this:

```
UPDATE customer_address_entity_varchar SET value = TRIM(value)
WHERE attribute_id=30;
```

BUT first you need to check whether the postcode's attribute ID is indeed 30 in customer_eav_attribute. The data model for the item with id 30 should be customer/attribute_data_postcode.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In this case I will continue using my code. I was able to adapt your MySQL statement a little bit. Just in case someone is interested using a single query:  `UPDATE customer_address_entity_varchar SET value = TRIM(value) WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM customer_eav_attribute WHERE data_model = "customer/attribute_data_postcode");`